# Opening a csv file in Excel vs. Notepad

Tags: c, excel, csv, notepad

Whenever I open a .csv file in Excel or Sakura Editor I get an fopen error when running my C program whereas when I open the file in Notepad or Notepad++ I don't get any errors and the file can be used by the program without issues.

What is the difference between the usage of the .csv file amongst these applications and why?

Comment: Notepad reads everything in memory and closes the file. Excel (and probably Sakura Editor) keeps file open without sharing permission you need (check fopen sharing you request) then you have an error when you try to open it in your C program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Excel, and presumably Sakura, open the file, they keep lock it with a share mode that denies other programs write access to the file. On the other hand, Notepad and Notepad++ open the file without locking it, and just read the contents.

If your program is just attempting to read the file, it will be able to succeed so long as you use the appropriate sharing mode. If your program wishes to modify the file, and Excel has it locked, then it will not succeed because of the lock.

Comment: Is there a reason as to why Excel or Sakura want to do so whereas Notepad++ and Notepad don't?

Comment: It's just different design choices made by the designers of these programs

Comment: I would like to believe that it was done in order to offer some kind of functionality right which is not possible with the other method. Is there anything of that sort?

Comment: Well, Excel's approach avoids the possibility of two apps making conflicting changes to the same file. Without a lock, prog A can write something, and then prog B can write something else, and whichever one wrote last wins. Open a file in NPP and Notepad. Change it in Notepad and save. Switch to NPP. Note that you get shown a dialog telling you that changes have been made and asking if you want to reload. Imagine if you have made changes in the NPP version. What do you do at that point. It's the classic issue of sharing a mutable resource.

Comment: Indeed, happens several times, is a little annoying at times too, but vice versa is equally annoying i.e having my program error out when an output file is made by the program and I have opened it up just to *view* it.